# How to open Outlook 2003 from command line and only launch ONE addin?

Tags: command-line-interface, outlook, outlook-2003, windows

My company is a lawfirm, and as such we use WAY too many Outlook add-ins and Word toolbars etc. But the firm wants them and so they're there. This causes the Outlook launch time to be a bit astronomical as all the add-ins are loaded and toolbars displayed. However, a good percentage of users only really use and need the ONE same add-in (which everyone MUST use). I know there are switches to launch Outlook with ALL add-ins disabled (like **outlook.exe /safe**), does anyone know a way to launch outlook with *all BUT one* (or two) add-ins disabled? Reason I'm looking for a command line solution for this is I'd like to give users two options - **Outlook Full** and **Outlook Fast** or something like that. If they need the extra functionality, they'll know to click the Full one etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a command line switch to specify which ones to load.  About your only options are:

1. Use /noextensions or /safe:3, then manually enable the one add-in.
2. Write a VBA macro that runs as Outlook loads that will disable them all and then enable just the one you're interested in.

Here's the [**command line reference for Outlook 2003**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP010031101033.aspx).

Comment: that's what I was expecting, not hoping for, but thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

You could open it once and disable all the add-ins you don't want to use on a regular basis.

See here for explanations: http://blog.techhit.com/5527-how-to-find-and-disable-outlook-2003-add-ins-and-plugins

Then you would by "default" only open Outlook with the one(s) you left enabled.  Then if the ones you disabled are needed again you'd re-enable them.